# C to Fortran calling problem

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, fortran

Using Visual Studio 9 on Windows 64 with Intel Fortran 10.1

I have a C function calling Fortran, passing a literal string "xxxxxx" (not null terminated) and the hidden passed length arg 6.

Fortran gets it right since the debugger recognizes it's a character(6) var and has the correct string, but when I try to assign another Fortran character*6 var to it I get the oddest error.

> `forrtl: severe (408): fort: (4):
>   Variable Vstring has substring ending
>   point 6 which is greater than the
>   variable length 6`

**-- C call --**

```
SETPR("abcdef",6);
```

**-- Fortran subroutine --**

```
subroutine setpr(vstring)

character*(*) vstring

character*6 prd

prd(1:6) = vstring(1:6)

return

end
```

Comment: add some code snippets, so that someone who knows Fortran can analyze them.

Comment: Indeed, some code would be helpful.  Especially the Fortran subroutine declaration and the call from C.

Comment: shoudn't that be `SETPR("abcdef",7);`? C strings have a trailing `'\0'`.

Comment: Fortran doesn't care about null termination. That's what the length arg is passed for. Note how C passes the 6 but the Fortran routine only declares the string. It's a shadow argument.

Comment: Have you had any luck sorting this out?

Comment: No. I've since gone to Intel fortran support and gotten no help there either. The root of the problem may be elsewhere spilling over on this variable space. common blocks...

Comment: Common blocks? Oh dear.  Does the snippet you posted work in isolation?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this with the Intel C compiler and the Intel Fortran compiler.  This gave, in C,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    extern void test_f_(char*, int);

    test_f_("abcdef",6);
}
```

and, in Fortran,

```
subroutine test_f(s)
    implicit none
    character*(*), intent(in) :: s

    character*6 :: c

    write (*,*) 'S is ', s
    write (*,*) 'Length of S is', len(s)

    c = s
    write (*,*) 'Implicit-copied C is ', c

    c(1:6) = s(1:6)
    write (*,*) 'Range-copied C is ', c
end subroutine test_f
```

When compiled and run, it produces

```
S is abcdef
Length of S is           6
Implicit-copied C is abcdef
Range-copied C is abcdef
```

What is your declaration in the C routine for the type of the Fortran routine?  Are you sure that the sizes of character and integer variables are the same between the C and Fortran code?

Comment: I'm not using the Intel C compiler here. That works fine on the Linux version. This problem is with the MSVC compiler on Windows.

Comment: Is the declaration in C of the Fortran routine the same as shown here?

Comment: Yes and no. The original is code I cannot share because the company is paranoid about releasing source. This is just one way to see it fail in the same manner.